# Unable to extract the rar from fedora

Tags: fedora

Unable to extract the rar from fedora as the packages are not available. So tried with yum install but it is not working ?

```
[root@sard-4191 ~]# yum install unrar
Loaded plugins: langpacks, presto, refresh-packagekit
Setting up Install Process
No package unrar available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

Comment: The package probably isn't called unrar.  I searched but couldn't find a list, try `rar`.

Answer (score 3):

For Fedora, `yum install rar` will provide what you need.

```
Usage:     rar <command> -<switch 1> -<switch N> <archive> <files...>
               <@listfiles...> <path_to_extract\>

<Commands>
  e             Extract files to current directory
```

Comment: "No package rar available." lol

Answer (score 3):

The `unrar` program is not included in the Fedora repositories [because it is not free software](http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Licensing:Unrar).

It is, however, available in the RPMFusion repository.  [Follow the instructions here to enable RPMFusion.](http://rpmfusion.org/Configuration)  Once you've done that, you can simply `yum install unrar`.